# How to order & count the number of duplicates for each unique value in R?

Tags: r, count, duplicates

I am working with scraped data on the housing market, and I have a dataset with some duplicates, found conditionally on a set of characteristics. Suppose I have observations A, B, and C with all characteristics being equal except the rent value and the dates (with dateA<dateB<dateC), I consider observations B and C as duplicates, as the ad was just re-posted on the webpage a second and then a third time in order to be re-rented.

I have created a column that tells me if each observation is a duplicate. So I see a column with the standard sequence of "FALSE" "TRUE" "FALSE" "FALSE" "TRUE" values.

I would like to create another column that tells me, in correspondence to the "TRUE", which is its ordinality. For example, in my example, I would like in correspondence to observation B to have the value 2 and in correspondence of the obs C the value 3 and so on.

Is there a way to do so in R?

Thanks.

Comment: Post output of `dput(head(data_frame_name, 20))`

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide any code or data, so it is quite difficult to provide an accurate answer.

However, suposing your data is `df`, using `dplyr` you could do the following:

```
df <- tibble(
  x = c(1:2,5,8,4),
  y = c(1:2,8,8,9),
  duplicated = c(TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE)
)

> df %>% 
+   group_by(duplicated) %>% 
+   mutate(ordinality = ifelse(duplicated,row_number(),NA))
# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Groups:   duplicated [2]
      x     y duplicated ordinality
  <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>           <int>
1     1     1 TRUE                1
2     2     2 TRUE                2
3     5     8 FALSE              NA
4     8     8 TRUE                3
5     4     9 FALSE              NA
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a column called "duplicates" with TRUE/FALSE values, you can use `group_by()` and `cumsum()` to count consecutive duplicates, e.g.

```
# Load libraries
library(tidyverse)

# Load dataset
data(us_rent_income)
df <- us_rent_income

# Create example dataset 
df2 <- df %>%
  bind_rows(., df, df, df) %>% 
  arrange(NAME) %>% 
  filter(variable == "rent") %>% 
  mutate(duplicates = ifelse(
    lag(NAME, n = 1, default = "FALSE") != NAME, "FALSE", "TRUE")
    ) %>% 
  select(NAME, variable, estimate, duplicates)

df2
## A tibble: 208 x 4
#   NAME    variable estimate duplicates
#   <chr>   <chr>       <dbl> <chr>     
# 1 Alabama rent          747 FALSE     
# 2 Alabama rent          747 TRUE      
# 3 Alabama rent          747 TRUE      
# 4 Alabama rent          747 TRUE      
# 5 Alaska  rent         1200 FALSE     
# 6 Alaska  rent         1200 TRUE      
# 7 Alaska  rent         1200 TRUE      
# 8 Alaska  rent         1200 TRUE      
# 9 Arizona rent          972 FALSE     
#10 Arizona rent          972 TRUE      

# Add the duplicate_ordinality column
df3 <- df2 %>% 
  group_by(NAME) %>% 
  mutate(duplicate_ordinality = cumsum(duplicates == "TRUE")) %>% 
  ungroup()

df3
## A tibble: 208 x 5
#   NAME    variable estimate duplicates duplicate_ordinality
#   <chr>   <chr>       <dbl> <chr>                     <int>
# 1 Alabama rent          747 FALSE                         0
# 2 Alabama rent          747 TRUE                          1
# 3 Alabama rent          747 TRUE                          2
# 4 Alabama rent          747 TRUE                          3
# 5 Alaska  rent         1200 FALSE                         0
# 6 Alaska  rent         1200 TRUE                          1
# 7 Alaska  rent         1200 TRUE                          2
# 8 Alaska  rent         1200 TRUE                          3
# 9 Arizona rent          972 FALSE                         0
#10 Arizona rent          972 TRUE                          1
```